# Failed to get request token method POST must have a request body

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to implement twitter login in my android app.
I've followed the instructions ( https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login ).

Everything is working fine if I have the twitter app installed but if I don't when I tap on the login button  I get the exception below.
It shoulw open a webview asking to login instead.

Any hint?

```
06-02 11:22:23.531  24124-24124/it.quepasa W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 39779: Lretrofit/client/OkClient;.openConnection (Lretrofit/client/Request;)Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;
06-02 11:22:23.611  24124-24124/it.quepasa E/Twitter﹕ Failed to get request token
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: method POST must have a request body.
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
06-02 11:22:23.686  24124-24124/it.quepasa E/Twitter﹕ Authorization completed with an error
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:78)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:198)
        at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.failure(Callback.java:28)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$2.run(CallbackRunnable.java:53)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here there is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="XXXXXXXX" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics()); //I've tried without crashlytics, same problem. Crashlytics works..
```

LoginActivity.java:

```
    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_buttons);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failure");
        }
    });
```

---

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a solution:

it is a breaking change in okhttp 2.4, reverting to 2.3 solved my problem.

See:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/751

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/854

Comment: Also seems that it's fixed in okhttp 2.5.

Comment: What does this mean? I'm only using  `compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.10.0@aar')..`? What can I do about this?